# Why do I get XMLHTTPRequest error on the following JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, native-code

I am trying to do native javascript and requesting an html page using the following JS code, why does it return (in Chrome) the following?

XMLHttpRequest cannot load /live-examples/temp.html. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

The code I am using is as follows:

```
            var sendRequest = (function(){

            // Private member variables
            var readyState = {
                UNSENT          : 0,
                OPENED          : 1,
                HEADERS_RECIVED : 2,
                LOADING         : 3,
                DONE            : 4
            }

            var status = {
                SUCCESS : 200,
                NOT_MODIFIED : 304
            }

            // Private member methods
            function getData(callBack){

                var xhr = getXhr();
                if(!xhr){
                    console.log('unable to create xhr object.')
                    return false;
                }

                // test readyState
                if(xhr.readyState !== readyState.DONE) return;

                if(xhr.status === status.SUCCESS && xhr.status !== status.NOT_MODIFIED){
                    callBack(xhr.responseText);
                }
            }


            function getXhr(){

                var XMLHttpList = [
                    function(){ return new XMLHttpRequest(); },
                    function(){ return ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); },
                    function(){ return ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }
                ], xhr;

                for(var i = 0; i < XMLHttpList.length; i++){
                    try{
                        xhr = XMLHttpList[i];
                        break;
                    }catch(e){
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                return xhr();
            }


            return function(url, callBack, postData){
                var xhr = getXhr();
                if(!xhr) return;

                var method = (postData) ? 'POST' : 'GET';

                xhr.open(method, url, true);
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                xhr.onreadystatechange = getData(callBack);

                xhr.send(postData);
            };

        })();

        function dealWithResponse(response){
            // the response from the xhr request
            console.log('success response: ' + response);
        }

        // cross origin request error.
        $(function(){
            document.getElementById('MyID').onclick = function(){ sendRequest('/live-examples/temp.html', dealWithResponse, 'GET'); }
        });
```

HTML code within the BODY is as follows:

```
<button id="MyID">I have a button!</button>
```

I checked the the file 'temp.html' does exist.

I am in this code just trying to show some simple ajax call using native javascript in a talk I am due to present.

Many thanks in Advance,
Quinton :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use HTTP when you want to access data using the XMLHTTPRequest object.

Comment: if you are on `http://example.com/foo/bar.html` and you request `/fizzbuzz.html`, _XMLHttpRequest_ knows you want `http://example.com/fizzbuzz.html` -- `var x = new XMLHttpRequest(); x.open('GET', '/foo'); x.send();`

Comment: @PaulS. — That's a different, although related, issue. The `Origin 'null'` indicates that `http` is not involved.

Comment: @PaulS.: But if you are on your local file system, and try to go request `/fizzbuzz.html`, the `file://` protocol gets used